# Unknown device in home network

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle, monitoring, smb

I have a home network that is behind NAT. My router IP address is 192.168.0.1 and DHCP is configured to provide addresses from the 192.168.0.1/24 range.

My desktop is connected trough the ethernet cable, but it is turned off at the moment. I am on my laptop right now.

When I monitor network traffic I see that my laptop is connected to 192.168.0.10:445. 445 is SMB(Samba) protocol and can be used for file sharing.

However 192.168.0.10 is an unknown device it's not my laptop's IP address. When I ping it reply back. When I connect to my network with my phone, ping also passes fine. So, the device definitely exists.

When I go to my router WiFi settings and list connected devices, the device is not showing up.

My router doesn't have an option to see devices connected trough cable.

What can I do? What is going on?

**UPDATE:**

I actually do have an option to see devices connected trough cable in my router, however the 192.168.0.10 isn't showing up.

However, another unknown device with the 192.168.0.14 address is showing up. But, when I try to ping 192.168.0.14 it doesn't reply back. It may be a left over from my previous desktop connection.

But, the address 192.168.0.10 is still replying to ping, and it doesn't show up in my router's connected devices, and it is connected to my laptop to port 445.

Comment: `When I monitor network traffic...` how do you monitor? What about starting by changing WiFi password?

Comment: I monitored network traffic on my laptop using nettop command on OS X. I'll try changing the password when I come home....But, still I am interested in what is going on? And why I don't see any the device listed in my router admin console.

Comment: I'll also try to install Wireshark to capture the traffic to try to see it's content and update my question with the details

Comment: what is your router type? I am asking because some routers feature SMB server which is listening on 445